# How do I check if a json array has valid data before I try and parse it?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out how to parse my json arrays before I do a data map and I'm not having much luck.

So let's say I want to check data.data.map(x => x.movementHistory[amt].statusHistory.conciseStatus) or data.data.map(x => x.movementHistory[amt].description) for data beforehand. How would I go about doing that?

I'm looking to have it check each data map before I do a request to avoid issues with error codes.

```
function ParseESTESShipmentStatus(movementhistory,amt)
{
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

    //test mode
    movementhistory = sheet.getRange("A10").getValue();
    amt = 0;

    var data = JSON.parse(movementhistory);

    var id = data.data.map(x => x.movementHistory[amt].description) ?? "test"

    Logger.log (id)
    var description = data.data.map(x => x.movementHistory[amt].description)
    var transportEventTypeCode = data.data.map(x => x.movementHistory[amt].transportEventTypeCode)

    var conciseStatus = data.data.map(x => x.movementHistory[amt].statusHistory.conciseStatus)
    var expandedStatus = data.data.map(x => x.movementHistory[amt].statusHistory.expandedStatus)
    var referenceDate = data.data.map(x => x.movementHistory[amt].statusHistory.referenceDate)
    var referenceTime = data.data.map(x => x.movementHistory[amt].statusHistory.referenceTime)
    var isException = data.data.map(x => x.movementHistory[amt].statusHistory.isException)

    var locationname = data.data.map(x => x.movementHistory[amt].location)
    var locationcode = data.data.map(x => x.movementHistory[amt].location.code)

    var address = data.data.map(x => x.movementHistory[amt].location.line)
    var city = data.data.map(x => x.movementHistory[amt].location.city)
    var state = data.data.map(x => x.movementHistory[amt].location.state)
    var postalCode = data.data.map(x => x.movementHistory[amt].location.postalCode)
    var telephone = data.data.map(x => x.movementHistory[amt].contact.telephone)


    Logger.log(telephone)

}
```

Example json

```
{
    "data": [
        {
             "movementHistory": [
                {
                    "id": "Pickup",
                    "description": "Actual Pickup",
                    "transportEventTypeCode": "Actual Pickup",
                    "statusHistory": [
                        {
                            "conciseStatus": "Departed Pickup Location",
                            "expandedStatus": "Pickup Location Serviced",
                            "referenceDate": "2022-11-10",
                            "referenceTime": "16:26:33-06:00",
                            "isException": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "144",
                    "description": "Origin Terminal",
                    "location": {
                        "name": "Waterloo",
                        "code": "WTL",
                        "address": {
                            "line": [
                                "2125 Commercial Street"
                            ],
                            "city": "Waterloo",
                            "state": "IA",
                            "postalCode": "50702"
                        },
                        "geoCoordinates": [
                            "-92.323624",
                            "42.484943"
                        ]
                    },
                    "contact": {
                        "telephone": "(319) 226-6414",
                        "fax": "13192266420"
                    },
                    "transportEventTypeCode": "Origin Terminal",
                    "statusHistory": [
                        {
                            "conciseStatus": "In Transit",
                            "expandedStatus": "Loaded at Estes facility at Waterloo, IA (144)",
                            "referenceDate": "2022-11-10",
                            "referenceTime": "19:07:42-06:00",
                            "isException": false
                        },
                        {
                            "conciseStatus": "In Transit",
                            "expandedStatus": "Trailer Closed at Estes facility at Waterloo, IA (144)",
                            "referenceDate": "2022-11-10",
                            "referenceTime": "20:31:37-06:00",
                            "isException": false
                        },
                        {
                            "conciseStatus": "In Transit",
                            "expandedStatus": "Departed Estes facility at Waterloo, IA (144)",
                            "referenceDate": "2022-11-10",
                            "referenceTime": "21:00:55-06:00",
                            "isException": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "137",
                    "description": "Planned Waypoint",
                    "location": {
                        "name": "Des Moines",
                        "code": "DMO",
                        "address": {
                            "line": [
                                "2201 East Ovid Avenue"
                            ],
                            "city": "Des Moines",
                            "state": "IA",
                            "postalCode": "50313"
                        },
                        "geoCoordinates": [
                            "-93.578027",
                            "41.625336"
                        ]
                    },
                    "contact": {
                        "telephone": "(515) 266-4910",
                        "fax": "15152660292"
                    },
                    "transportEventTypeCode": "Planned Waypoint",
                    "statusHistory": [
                        {
                            "conciseStatus": "In Transit",
                            "expandedStatus": "En route to Estes facility at Des Moines, IA (137)",
                            "referenceDate": "2022-11-10",
                            "referenceTime": "21:00:55-06:00",
                            "isException": false
                        },
                        {
                            "conciseStatus": "In Transit",
                            "expandedStatus": "Arrived at Estes facility at Des Moines, IA (137)",
                            "referenceDate": "2022-11-10",
                            "referenceTime": "23:04:00-06:00",
                            "isException": false
                        },
                        {
                            "conciseStatus": "In Transit",
                            "expandedStatus": "Loaded at Estes facility at Des Moines, IA (137)",
                            "referenceDate": "2022-11-11",
                            "referenceTime": "00:48:46-06:00",
                            "isException": false
                        },
                        {
                            "conciseStatus": "In Transit",
                            "expandedStatus": "Trailer Closed at Estes facility at Des Moines, IA (137)",
                            "referenceDate": "2022-11-11",
                            "referenceTime": "01:17:36-06:00",
                            "isException": false
                        },
                        {
                            "conciseStatus": "In Transit",
                            "expandedStatus": "Departed Estes facility at Des Moines, IA (137)",
                            "referenceDate": "2022-11-11",
                            "referenceTime": "02:19:12-06:00",
                            "isException": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "133",
                    "description": "Destination Terminal",
                    "location": {
                        "name": "Mankato",
                        "code": "MNK",
                        "address": {
                            "line": [
                                "3495 3rd Avenue North"
                            ],
                            "city": "Mankato",
                            "state": "MN",
                            "postalCode": "56001"
                        },
                        "geoCoordinates": [
                            "-93.994492",
                            "44.205618"
                        ]
                    },
                    "contact": {
                        "telephone": "(507) 345-5418",
                        "fax": "15073456873"
                    },
                    "transportEventTypeCode": "Destination Terminal",
                    "statusHistory": [
                        {
                            "conciseStatus": "In Transit",
                            "expandedStatus": "En route to delivery facility at Mankato, MN (133)",
                            "referenceDate": "2022-11-11",
                            "referenceTime": "02:19:13-06:00",
                            "isException": false
                        },
                        {
                            "conciseStatus": "In Transit",
                            "expandedStatus": "Arrived at Mankato, MN (133) delivery facility",
                            "referenceDate": "2022-11-11",
                            "referenceTime": "05:39:42-06:00",
                            "isException": false
                        },
                        {
                            "conciseStatus": "In Transit",
                            "expandedStatus": "Loaded for delivery at Mankato, MN (133) delivery facility",
                            "referenceDate": "2022-11-11",
                            "referenceTime": "08:54:51-06:00",
                            "isException": false
                        },
                        {
                            "conciseStatus": "In Transit",
                            "expandedStatus": "Trailer Closed for delivery at Mankato, MN (133) delivery facility",
                            "referenceDate": "2022-11-11",
                            "referenceTime": "08:54:51-06:00",
                            "isException": false
                        },
                        {
                            "conciseStatus": "In Transit",
                            "expandedStatus": "Assigned to Driver at Mankato, MN (133) delivery facility",
                            "referenceDate": "2022-11-11",
                            "referenceTime": "08:55:49-06:00",
                            "isException": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "Delivery",
                    "description": "Actual Delivery",
                    "transportEventTypeCode": "Delivery",
                    "statusHistory": [
                        {
                            "conciseStatus": "Out for Delivery",
                            "expandedStatus": "Out for delivery",
                            "referenceDate": "2022-11-11",
                            "referenceTime": "09:15:48-06:00",
                            "isException": false
                        },
                        {
                            "conciseStatus": "Out for Delivery",
                            "expandedStatus": "Arrived at delivery location",
                            "referenceDate": "2022-11-11",
                            "referenceTime": "14:09:26-06:00",
                            "isException": false
                        },
                        {
                            "conciseStatus": "Out for Delivery",
                            "expandedStatus": "Unloaded at delivery location",
                            "referenceDate": "2022-11-11",
                            "referenceTime": "14:09:27-06:00",
                            "isException": false
                        },
                        {
                            "conciseStatus": "Delivered",
                            "expandedStatus": "Delivery Completed - OK",
                            "referenceDate": "2022-11-11",
                            "referenceTime": "14:15:15-06:00",
                            "reasonCode": "OK",
                            "reason": "Delivery Completed - OK",
                            "isException": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "disclaimers": [
                "Freight Charges are subject to change upon audit.",
                "Freight Charges are shown on shipments for which the logged in user is the payor of the freight charges.",
                "Reported Delivery Date is subject to change upon verification.",
                "Reported delivery time is subject to change based upon verification."
            ]
        }
    ],
    "error": {
        "code": 0,
        "message": "",
        "details": ""
    }
}
```

I've tried nullish coalescing operators and no luck.

Comment: Use an online JSON validator

Comment: There is no data.data

Comment: Check again. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I had to modify the code like this.

```
    const id = data.data.map(obj => obj?.movementHistory[amt]?.id ?? '');
    const description = data.data.map(obj => obj?.movementHistory[amt]?.description ?? '');

    const transportEventTypeCode = data.data.map(obj => obj?.movementHistory[amt]?.transportEventTypeCode ?? '');

    const conciseStatus = data.data.map(obj => obj?.movementHistory[amt]?.conciseStatus ?? '');
    const expandedStatus = data.data.map(obj => obj?.movementHistory[amt]?.expandedStatus ?? '');
    const referenceDate = data.data.map(obj => obj?.movementHistory[amt]?.referenceDate ?? '');
    const referenceTime = data.data.map(obj => obj?.movementHistory[amt]?.referenceTime ?? '');
    const isException = data.data.map(obj => obj?.movementHistory[amt]?.isException ?? '');

    const locationname = data.data.map(obj => obj?.movementHistory[amt]?.locationname ?? '');
    const locationcode = data.data.map(obj => obj?.movementHistory[amt]?.location.code?? '');
```